# Linux kernel version with (uname -r) does not show distribution version, where can I get the kernel source for this kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I'm trying to compile a specific kernel module for my linux machine running on a hosted dedicated VPS. The VPS instance is running `Ubuntu 20.04 64bit`.
In order to get the source code for the kernel I need to find out the exact kernel version. When I run `uname -r` I get this value: `5.4.0`

Since there is no hyphen in the version number I'm not sure where to get the source code and kernel headers for my kernel.

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm not very experienced with Linux.

Comment: Where did the kernel come from? If you don't know, ask the person who installed it.

Comment: I already asked the VPS support about the exact version number but they were of little help. Hostinger VPS is really bad.

Comment: There are a million VPS providers out there. No reason to stay with one that has bad service or does questionable things to their VMs.

Comment: I'm switching as soon as my one month subscription ends but Im stuck with them until then.

Comment: @dihit32745 what is inside /proc/version? And maybe -v option for uname (kernel version) will help you searching for the source code.